# What DNSs have API access?

Tags: api, service, dns

I saw this over on slashdot and realized if I could program in dns control into some of my apps it would make life a lot easier. [Someone over there](http://ask.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=975011&cid=25146235) recommended [dynect](http://dynect.com/features/api.html) which apparently had a wonderful api. Unfortunately not a lot else was recomended. I don't know anything about managing dns servers I mostly work with the lamp stack, so on linux I understand bind is the way to go but other then a basic setup I'd be lost. I'd rather outsource the details.

What DNS services have API's and are easy to use without breaking the bank?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to that question as well.

Comment: Then vote this up so people see it, I'm still looking for it too. The best I've come across is slicehost's api for their webpanel. It includes dns, but their dns is still basic.

Comment: I don't think there will ever be a correct answer for this question. Should it be closed or flagged somehow? Community wiki?

Comment: Wizard, just because a question does not have a definitive answer does not mean it's a bad question. In fact, I believe the best questions are the ones that have no correct answers, because it shows us all where work needs to be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess in the last 3 years this is a bit of a solved problem. Here are some to check out:

- Amazon has a nice dns service now http://aws.amazon.com/route53/
- Linode has a free api based dns if you're a customer.
- Dynadot has a fee dns with an api if you're a customer.

Comment: mmm, know any of them that support xml-rpc?

Answer (score 5):

Hey I haven't used them, but Zerigo looks promising.  We will probably wind up going with them if they allow enough hosts.  Their API is standard REST stuff... very straightforward.

http://www.zerigo.com/docs/apis/dns/1.1

Thanks,

Eric.

Comment: I've been very happy with Zerigo. Reliable service, great interface and API, and a very reasonable price.

Answer (score 3):

We use DjbDNS and it's backended onto MySQL so we just hit the DB to make changes and periodically rebuild the the config data.

Comment: That still requires running your own servers. I'm hoping for something a little bit more robust then the scattered machines my stuff is running on.

Answer (score 3):

Has anyone seen any of the following DNS providers with APIs:

- http://durabledns.com/
- https://dnsimple.com/ (also supports registration by API)
- http://www.loaddns.com/

Answer (score 2):

We use [Zonomi](http://zonomi.com). Its very cheap and never gone down for us. With API

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://customdns.ca. I have a couple of domains with them - no problems so far. They provide RestFul API.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dns.com

Here's the link to the API documentation:

https://github.com/dnsdotcom/API_DOC/

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used the api, but I have been using the registrar for 10+ years and never had a problem:  namecheap.com

Here is the API [intro](https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/intro.aspx).
Here is the API [methods list](https://www.namecheap.com/support/api/methods.aspx).

Pretty comprehensive.  From purchasing to host and e-mail forwarding setup.