# How can I create subdomains programmatically in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, routes

Is there any way to create subdomains via code and route them to my main domain?

`product123.domain.com` instead of `www.domain.com/products/?id=123`

Comment: You need some sort of API to control DNS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133458/what-dnss-have-api-access

Answer (score 8):

We do the same thing, but do not generate the DNS records with code. Instead we create a wildcard DNS entry, resolving all subdomains to a given IP. Inside code, we retreive the subdomain from the request URI and use it for further processing.

We use Route53 DNS by amazon, and have an A entry like this

*.ourblogsite.com 184.5.5.5

Which resolves all subdomains to that IP address. Inside IIS we bind an application to port 80 of that IP rather than hostname, which will handle any requests. The Web application is an MVC application, which breaks apart the request URI and fishes the subdomain portion out. We use this to power the somename.ourblogsite.com functionality, where somename is a unique identifier given by the client.