# Azure Websites and VIP Swaping

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I'm currently using Azure Websites to deploy my app. I'm currently using two websites each listening to a different branch of my GIT. As seen [here](http://www.bradygaster.com/multiple-environments-with-windows-azure-web-sites).

Now, for it to be perfect, I'm only missing a way to quickly switch between these 2 instances so I could:

- Deploy on A
- Test the changes on A
- VIP Swap A with B
- Change code
- Deploy on B
- Test the changes on B
- VIP Swap B with A
- ...

Anyone has accomplished anything like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VIP swapping between a production and a staging deployment is ***now*** possible with Azure Web Sites.

It works similarly to how VIP swapping works with Azure Cloud Services.

You can find details on how to set this up and use it in [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2014/01/16/windows-azure-staging-publishing-support-for-web-sites-monitoring-improvements-hyper-v-recovery-manager-ga-and-pci-compliance.aspx).

Comment: For the record, VIP swapping is now available on WAWS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that you'd need to find a DNS provider that could give you access to DNS mapping via an API.  This way, you could use a script to call the DNS and swap the C-Names around.

This Stackoverflow post talks about DNS providers that allow an API access: [What DNSs have API access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133458/what-dnss-have-api-access)